# How to convert multiple nodes with the same name in XML to df/list in R?

Tags: xml, r

This is my first experience with XML using R. So my question will probably sound very naive if not silly...
I downloaded an XML file in the pattern of

```
<experiment>
  <sampleattribute>
    <category>AGE</category>
    <value>8</value>
    <value>10</value>
    <value>11</value>
  </sampleattribute>
  <sampleattribute>
    <category>SEX</category>
    <value>female</value>
    <value>male</value>
  </sampleattribute>
</experiment>
<experiment>
  <sampleattribute>
    <category>DESIGN</category>
    <value>control</value>
    <value>disease</value>
  </sampleattribute>
</experiment>
<experiment>
  <sampleattribute>
    <category>AGE</category>
    <value>8</value>
    <value>10</value>
    <value>11</value>
  </sampleattribute>
  <sampleattribute>
    <category>SEX</category>
    <value>female</value>
  </sampleattribute>
  <sampleattribute>
    <category>DESIGN</category>
    <value>control</value>
    <value>disease</value>
  </sampleattribute>
</experiment>
```

As you can see, each experiment nodes have different sampleattribute. I want to concatenate all the sampleattribute in each experiment in a way that it will be converted into a dataframe eventually.

I have tried attr<- xpathSApply(myxml, "//experiment/sampleattribute"), but there is no way to track back which experiment has what sampleattirbutes.

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a `dataframe` with such XML but rather a list.

Using `XML` package you can do the this for example:

```
doc = htmlParse(txt,asText=TRUE)

res = lapply(xpathSApply(doc,'//experiment'),
       function(x){
         category = xpathSApply(x,'sampleattribute/category',xmlValue)
         values = xpathSApply(x,'sampleattribute/value',xmlValue)
         list(category=category,
              values =values)
       })
```

Then you can inspect you result :

```
 str(res)
 List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ category: chr [1:2] "AGE" "SEX"
  ..$ values  : chr [1:5] "8" "10" "11" "female" ...
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ category: chr "DESIGN"
  ..$ values  : chr [1:2] "control" "disease"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ category: chr [1:3] "AGE" "SEX" "DESIGN"
  ..$ values  : chr [1:6] "8" "10" "11" "female" ..
```

Comment: Thanks. But The same question persists that there is no way to track back that first 2 belong to node 1, and last 3 belong to node3.